# CASE Statement in SQL Server to get output I need

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, case

So a friend of mine told me to check the almost 5 million email addresses that got 'Hacked' on Gmail.

I downloaded the file a text file, with almost 5 million emails (4804288). I figured I'd just open it in my text editor and Ctrl+F my email address. Well it took forever to just open the `.txt` document and it crashed. I then exported it to Excel but it has a limit of 1 million+ rows. Since I'm studying SQL I figured I'll just load it into SQL Server and query it creating a stored procedure. It should be cool.

So.. what did I do?

Created a table called `5Mil`.

And bulk inserted the info from the `.txt` file:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[5Mil]
FROM 'C:\list\google.txt'
WITH (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '@gmail.com')
GO
```

First question, since the txt file had one line per email without a ',' at the end the only way I could load the info was using the `rowterminator = '@gmail.com'` which truncated `'@gmail.com'` and left only the username part of the email.

Maybe someone can help me understand how to import the information including the `@gmail.com`.

I was able to import the email addresses 1 per row. total rows 4804288.

So far so good.

I am currently learning CTE's so I figured I'd apply this to my stored procedure.

This is what I did.

```
CREATE PROC googlemails
   @email VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
   WITH CTE AS
   (
      SELECT Emails
      FROM dbo.[5Mil]
      WHERE Emails LIKE '%'+@email+'%'
   )
   SELECT 
      CASE 
         WHEN Emails IS NOT NULL  
           THEN Emails
           ELSE 'you are safe'
        END AS 'Google Email'
   FROM CTE
```

When I run the procedure and it finds emails it properly lists them.

But when I put an email address that's not in the list I get

> Google Email

Blank. What I want is to be able to show `'You are safe'` letting the user know that your email was not part of the 5 Mill 'hacked'.

What would be the proper way to use the `CASE` statement here. Or like always other ways of accomplishing this task. For learning purposes.

Thank you.

Comment: If you just want to find if your name is in there, why don't you try using a find ad replace tool like this one https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/ to find your name. I'm interested to know if it will work on a file this big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select case when exists( select 1 from 5MIL WHERE Emails LIKE '%'+@email+'%') 
            then 'hacked' 
            else 'not hacked' end
```

CTE not appropriate here; they're mostly for simplifying large queries and for recursive queries.

Comment: What if instead of 'hacked' i'd like to show the item(s) that match that query.

If a user entered just the letter 't' it will show hacked but there could be hundreds of rows with the letter 't'.

Show those.

Comment: @user3255598 OK, this answer is based on your original intention (case statement) and is designed to return a binary result (only ever one row; 2 possible values), not a result set.  If you want to return all matches, it's just a matter of returning what's in the "exists" above replacing "1" with "Emails".  This would give you a resultset with a single column, "Emails" (many rows).  Of course, that would fundamentally change your sproc...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you now have a table called 5Mil with one column called Email each with a username without the "@gmail.com". It is unnecessarily redundant to append "@gmail.com" to each one.
Soooo.... why not just search for the username part? Using a LIKE '%email%' is slow and inefficient. Much simpler to just to do this in your stored procedure (similar to dudNumber4's answer but don't use "LIKE"):

```
--SET @Email = 'someusername' -- note no "@gmail.com"
if EXISTS(SELECT 1 from 5Mil where Email = @Email)
  SELECT 'Hacked'
ELSE
  SELECT "Not hacked"
```

if you create an index on 5Mil.Email the search will be almost instant.